# Webscraping: nested for loop only writing to last dataframe in the list

Tags: pandas, list, dataframe, web-scraping, nested-loops

I am attempting to use a nested for loop to pull data from different web pages (salary information for each player on every MLB team), with each scraped web page being written to its own Pandas DataFrame. I'm getting all of the data I want, but it's only being written to the last DataFrame in the list.

```
l = {}
for name in name_list:
    l[name] = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Player','Salary','% of Payroll'])
 
#create a for loop to scrape all urls and write each to their df
    
for page in url_list:
    url = page
    response=requests.get(url).text
    soup=bs(response, 'html.parser')
    sleep(randint(1,10))
    table=soup.find('tbody')
    for row in table.find_all('tr'):
        col=row.find_all('a')
        player=col[0].string
        col=row.find_all('td')
        payroll=col[7].text
        percent=col[9].string
        l[name]=l[name].append({'Player':player,'Salary':payroll,'% of Payroll':percent}, ignore_index=True) 
        
print(l)
```

Snippet of output:

```
Index: [], 'St. Louis Cardinals': Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Player, Salary, % of Payroll]
Index: [], 'Tampa Bay Rays': Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Player, Salary, % of Payroll]
Index: [], 'Texas Rangers': Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Player, Salary, % of Payroll]
Index: [], 'Toronto Blue Jays': Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Player, Salary, % of Payroll]
Index: [], 'Washington Nationals':                 Player        Salary % of Payroll
0    Madison Bumgarner  $23,000,000         23.69
1          Ketel Marte   $8,500,000         11.19
2        David Peralta   $8,000,000         10.53
3        Mark Melancon   $6,000,000          7.90
4        Merrill Kelly   $5,583,333          7.35
..                 ...           ...          ...
919     Andres Machado           -0          0.00
920     Patrick Murphy           -0          0.00
921        Josh Rogers           -0          0.00
922       Keibert Ruiz           -0          0.00
923        Lane Thomas           -0          0.00

[924 rows x 3 columns]}
```

The information is being pulled fully and correctly, but only written to the final DF in the list. I have a feeling the issue is something simple like indentation, etc. but I'm out of ideas and experiments! Thank you in advance.

Comment: You aren't iterating over the `name_list` in the last for-loop. Try to change it to `for name, page in zip(name_list, url_list):`

Comment: @AndrejKesely you're exactly right; that did it. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

From @AndrejKesely's advice, the appropriate fix was

```
for name, page in zip(name_list, url_list):
```

Immediate fix, my original code was not iterating over the name list and therefore not writing to the named DF each time.